# SVG inside an HTML-Object

Tags: javascript, html, object, svg

I have built a website with 2 SVG-files, each one inside an object tag.
Chrome returns 'null' when I try to access the SVG-Root element with .getSVGDocument() and also with .contentDocument (!). In Opera I have the same problem. In Firefox and Safari it works.
I heard that Chrome denies access to external files by default, for security reasons. Hence, the only way to solve the problem is to put the SVG-Code inline HTML !? Or is there another option?

Thanks for your hints!

Kind regards,
Codebastler

Comment: Thats the best way to just inline svg in your html,  it enables whole lot more features and abilities through js and css

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Sachin. Today I have found out that my application works in Chrome when I run it on my localhost. I did not change the way of embedding the SVG-files (html-objects). Obviously, the reason for my problem was not the usage of .getSVGDocument() or .contentDocument (!). For explanation: I use 2 AJAX-requests with jQuery ($.getJSON) to retrieve data for the dynamic generation of svg elements.